# show hide side menu on different components reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, routes, react-router

As I am new on React js. I tried many solutions to implement the show/hide side menu on differnt components.

My scenarios is:

1. When user is loggedin then side menu shows on all components.
2. When user is loggedout then It shows only some of the components like ForgotPassword or Terms and condition(menus name changed as per the authentication) but hides on Login Component.

My code is:

App.js

```
        <Router>
            <SideNavigation />           
            <Routes />
        </Router>
```

Routes.js

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
      <PrivateRoutes exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
      <PrivateRoutes exact path="/emp" component={Employee} />
      <PrivateRoutes exact path="/empList" component={EmployeeList} />
    </Switch>
```

Comment: why don't you check your loging status in the app.js if your user logged in you can show sidenavigatioın

Comment: Hi @OzanManav....thanks for reply............ Yes I can do that but the thing is I have to show side menu on forgot password component and in this case it doesn't work

Comment: then you can use this field in the sidenavigation component ? if logged in show all ones, else show only forgot password ?

Comment: No i have some other components also forgot username term and condition kind of that will include side navigation without authentication